# Not able to download file from internet url in java

Tags: java, download

i want to download a csv file from a internet url.
I have tried every code that i can find online and not able to download.

```
           URL google = new URL("myurl");
           ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(google.openStream());
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://excelsheet.csv");
           fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
```

This code is not working

I used this function , it is not working too.

```
public stacvoid saveUrl(String filename, String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try
        {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
                fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
                {
                        fout.write(data, 0, count);
                }
        }
        finally
        {
                if (in != null)
                        in.close();
                if (fout != null)
                        fout.close();
        }
    }
```

I tried a simple input stream on my url , that doesn't work too.

```
           URL oracle = new URL("myurl");
           URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                          yc.getInputStream()));
```

Now instead of myurl , if i type any other url , the bufferedreader does get data.
If I enter myurl in a browser i get a popup to save or download the csv file.
So the problem is not with an incorrrect "myurl"

Is it possible that the servelet/code running on "myurl" actually checks if the request is coming from a browser and only then sends the data.

Thanks everyone . Used httpclient and it works for me. Heres the code that downloads an csv file , saves it locally and then reads it and parses all the tokens.

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("your url to download");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

           System.out.println(response.getProtocolVersion());
           System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
           System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
           System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
            HttpEntity entity =    response.getEntity();
           if (entity != null) {
               FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream("C://excelsheet.csv");
               entity.writeTo(fos);
               fos.close();
           }

           //create BufferedReader to read csv file
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("C://excelsheet.csv"));
      String strLine = "";
      StringTokenizer st = null;
       int lineNumber = 0, tokenNumber = 0;
      while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
                              {
                                      lineNumber++;

                                      //break comma separated line using ","
                                      st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ",");

                                      while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                                      {
                                              //display csv values
                                              tokenNumber++;
                                              System.out.println("Line # " + lineNumber +
                                                              ", Token # " + tokenNumber
                                                              + ", Token : "+ st.nextToken());
                                      }

                                      //reset token number
                                      tokenNumber = 0;

                              } 
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("insdie the catch part");
           System.out.println(e.toString());
       }
```

Comment: Can you get to the file, using a browser, if you're not logged in to the website?

Comment: What does not work with `Channels`, do you get an exception? You may not have write access to the root of C drive.

Comment: What error message do you get when you run your code?

Comment: What is surprising is that i do not get any error message , or code does not go into exception block
I get this at the console , which i guess is normal completion.
Process exited with exit code 0.

Comment: Meta advice: replace every occurrence of "not working" in your question with an explanation of 1. what it is doing and 2. what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) lib?
I used it sometime ago to download a set of exams from a site automatically.

Comment: yes using a browser i can get to the file , without any logging in , though it takes some time

Comment: Yes, but when it works, is nice. My app to download exams is: [PCI Downloader](http://www.davidfeitosa.com/p/downloads.html). Unhappy, I lost the source code, but it still works.

Comment: i tried Apache commons  FileUtils.copyURLToFile(oracle,f); but this did not work too

Comment: @user1256070 and the HttpClient, have you tested it?

Comment: @user1256070 could please you mark this answer as the one that solves your problem?